# Using CSS to make a sliding transition out of another DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project with HTML/CSS/Javascript, one hickup I've been trying to solve for hours now is a transition in which one div slides down from behind another, think as a slide phone where you slide the keyboard out from behind the screen.

I have the hover functions and everything except the animation actually works.

You can see my code down below, although it might be a bit messy.

```css
.hover {}

.productcontent {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.productcontent:hover {
  height: 300px;
}

.hover:hover+.productcontent {
  display: block;
  transition: height 1s;
}

.productcontent:hover {
  display: block;
}

.productcontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="zoom">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="hover">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/500/500.jpg?hmac=idOEkrJhLd7nEU5pNrAGCyJ6HHJdR_sit1qDt5J3Wo0" alt="Mr Fijiwiji" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="productcontent">
        <h1>Iris</h1>
        <p>By Mr Fijiwiji and Matt Van</p>
        <p class="price">$1.00</p>
        <audio src="songs/mrfijiwiji.mp3" controls> 
    <embed 
        src="songs/mrfijiwiji.mp3"
        width="50px"
        height="20px"
        loop="false"
        autostart="false">
  </audio>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will also link an image to what it's actually supposed to look like with images and such:
[Before soon-to-be animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giu8H.png)

[After soon-to-be animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjSlD.png)

Hopefully this describes my problem well enough. And maybe someone out there can help me with this.

NOTE!: I own none of the art or pictures in this, it's just for a school project that will not be used commercially!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 main properties that are causing troubles here are `display` and `height`. They just need a bit of updating to get the animation to work as intended.

Right now, on the main hover, the `display` property is being set from `none` to `block`. This is the only change that occurs on hover (the height of the `.productcontent` is not being altered at this moment).

Rather than hiding the `.productcontent` using the `display` property, try using the `visibility` property. This property is a lot simpler to animate using CSS alone.

The height property cannot animate from its default `auto` state. To animate height in CSS, there needs a defined value to animate from. If it's intended to from a hidden state, we can set the height to `0`.

```
.productcontent {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

By defining the hover state's `height` within the `.productcontent:hover` selector, the height `transition` will not take effect until you hover the `.productcontent` element. Since this element is already set to be showing when the `.hover` element is hovered, the height transition will not be apparent. So, the height property should be moved to the main hover selector if we want to see the animation:

```
.hover:hover + .productcontent {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 300px;
  transition: height 1s;
}
```

That all being said, if you want more of a "slide" effect, rather than animating the height, it might be better to use the `transform: translateY()` property.